React dnd-kit active element issues when drag element in popup that was transformed
Hello folks I faced with a problem when active element losing its correct position if its parent has a transform property
I created codesandbox to show what I mean. Here I kinda simulating that my list can be in a popup that is floating and in positioning styles uses transform property. For example in my real app I use floating-ui hook to place my popup and its kinda ruining the styles of dnd.
Any ideas here what to do? I tried to create custom modifiers, but can not catch or check parents styles?
